# boost and mollom: if both are configured, boost doesn't cache the page which consists of mollom enabled form

Tags: caching, drupal, captcha, drupal-boost

boost drupal module and mollom drupal module: if both are configured, boost doesn't cache the page which consists of mollom enabled form

I configured boost and caching was successful for the expected page.

But after enabling mollom module and its captcha functionality for a form place within that page, caching for this page has stopped.

To recheck if the problem is because of mollom, i disable mollom captcha and checked. It worked fine.

Can anybody explain a certain approach for caching this page or solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: 'boost' - drupal module used for caching drupal based sites

Comment: can you please create something like - 'drupal-boost'

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: for mollom configuration, disabled captcha option, enabled text analysis option